# Регулярка от конкретного до любого первого из списка

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как выбирать до первого из списка?

например со start до либо end либо fin
пробовал так:

```
start(.*)(?!(end|fin))+?
```

но берет до последнего вхождения...

Comment: Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то вам надо ".*" заменить на ".+" или ".*?"

Comment: да, ".*?" помогло, спасибо... и чего сразу не попробовал) ох уж эти регулярки %) спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, вы перемудрили. Вроде, работает

```
start(.*?)(end|fin)
```

https://regex101.com/r/XXPrcF/3

Comment: Не советую использовать такое выражение [с длинными строками](https://regex101.com/r/XXPrcF/4).

Comment: в данном случае end и fin будут входить в подстановку, мне же надо старт входит, и ДО end или fin, не включая их :)

Comment: @ShutTap `start(.*?)(?=end|fin)`.

Comment: да, уже работает) спасибо большое еще раз всем :)